# Are renamed clocks synchronous?

Tags: verilog, fpga

Let's say I have a code:

```
wire clk1;
wire clk2;
assign clk1 = Clk;
assign Clk2 = Clk;
```

Now clk1 and clk2 are used to clock various modules and traverse through the hierarchy of the design. Somewhere deep in the hierarchy, if a module is clocked by clk1, does it's output remain synchronous with another from module2?

e.g.

```
reg r1;
always @ (posedge clk1)
    r1 <= rSomething;

reg r2;
always @ (posedge clk2)
    r2 <= r1;
```

Is this code valid? Will the synthesis tools (Altera tool chain) maintain the skew across these two clocks? Or will it maintain the skew only on clocks that are named the same and clk1 and clk2 will cease to be synchronous despite their common source?

Thanks

EDIT1 : This for synthesis, not simulation.

EDIT2: Changed the second code example. I was trying to assign r2 <= r1, not the other way round as we the case earlier.

Comment: Is this question related to synthesis and/or simulation?

Comment: @Paebbels : It's more of a synthesis question, because derived clocks tend to perform ideally in simulation and so hide problems you'll get on the synthesised design. Clock trees and derived clocks can still cause some odd effects in simulation though.

Comment: @PaulS I know, that why I asked the OP to clarify his question. So others can formulated a precise answer :)

Comment: This is related to synthesis. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A synthesizer will transform your design input into an internal netlist that represents the logic structure. This is typically done in two stages. First to a high level behavioral form that represents abstract operations and then to a technology mapped form that directly implements logic primitives of the target architecture. In this transformation process `clk1` and `clkl2` will be seen as topologically equivalent to `clk` and they will be treated as one combined net.

The normal clock buffer insertion process will account for the skew across all leaf nodes in the unified net. Any timing constraints would need to be put on `clk`. An attempt to constrain `clk1` and `clk2` independently could have unpredictable results.

Comment: Some timing analysis tools allow the definition of different constraints on subtrees which have a common parent node. This is assured if the tool propagates constraints strictly from node to it's child nodes. However, I haven't found any practical use for this feature :)

Answer (score 3):

Renamed clocks remain synchronous. An explicit continuous assignment is similar to passing a signal through a port where the connecting signal name and the port name are different. As far as synthesis tools are concerned they are just name aliases for the same signal.

However, results could be disturbed if the RTL code has simulation races. If you used a blocking assignment to `r1`, then the order of execution between the two `always` blocks would lead to a simulation/synthesis mismatch.

Comment: Thanks. For your second part - that was a typo, I corrected it in the original post.

Comment: How about the delta created by the continuous assignment? Is the code really correct? I have a debate on AMD’s forum because I get a much worse synthesis QoR once I reassigned a clock like OP.

Comment: @Alexis, There is no "delta" created by a continuous assignment. Se my updated answer.